# remove 404 error while refreshing SPA of Angular 8 without hash(#) routing

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I'm encountering a 404 error when refreshing my Angular app hosted alongside an ASP.NET Core Web API in IIS. Despite adding rewrites in the web.config file, the issue persists. My base URL is configured as follows:

```
<base href="/">
```

Here's the content of the web.config file located in the wwwroot folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
          <rules>
            <rule name="AngularJS Routes" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url=".*" />
              <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />   
              </conditions>
              <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
            </rule>
          </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <httpErrors>
            <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
            <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/index.html" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        </httpErrors>
      </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

I've tried several solutions without success. Could anyone assist me with resolving this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: change the rule name to <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true"> and remove the content of httpErrors as well the tag

Comment: @LuigiWoodhouse thank u for your comment, but I tried this but still getting 404 error :/

Comment: is your angular app deployed on azure? I am noticed your base url is blank. should it not have the url of the app?

Comment: I am using IIS, "should it not have the url of the app", <base href="/">, it means that all relative URLs will be relative to the root of mybdomain. So if the Angular application is deployed at https://example.com/, then all relative URLs will be resolved relative to https://example.com/.

Comment: For this issue, my suggestion is to compile Angular  project and handle it as  static files. For more details, you can check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78020750/7687666

Comment: If we can use the SPA structure, then we don't need to use the rewrite rules in IIS.

Comment: @JasonPan Thank you very much for your suggestion! Your solution worked perfectly and saved me a lot of time. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, can I summarize the comment as answer below ? Hope it can help others who will face the same issue in the future,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your scenario, this can be achieved by using URL Rewrite from the `machine level`, but I don't recommend it for the simple reason that it will bring challenges to future upgrades or deployments.

But my suggestion is to prefer to solve the problem from the `code level`, which will be more user-friendly and will be compatible with Linux and other systems.

We can achieve this through the middleware of static files in asp.net core, which is as simple as the following.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();


app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseAuthorization();


app.MapControllers();
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

app.Run();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion! Your solution worked perfectly and saved me a lot of time. I really appreciate your help!