# How to prevent a 404 error when refreshing an angular application that has already been published to IIS 10

Tags: c#, angular, iis, angular-ui-router, asp.net-core-webapi

I have deployed my .NET API to IIS10 and inside the directory where the .NET files are I have a wwwroot folder where I have placed my published angular files. Within the same wwwroot folder ,amongst these files, there is also a web config that specifies the rewrite URL as shown below.

The apps seems to login and display fine until I refresh then I get a 404.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
            <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG, DELETE, PUT" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" responseBufferLimit="0" />
        </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <!--<action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />-->
          <action type="Rewrite" url="wwwroot/index.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

In app.modules.ts

```
providers: [
    {provide : LocationStrategy , useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
  ]
```

RouterModule.forRoot

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
...
const routes: Routes = [//routes in here];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

snippet of index.html

```
<html class="loading" lang="en" data-textdirection="ltr" data-critters-container>

<head><link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <base href="/">

  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimal-ui">
  <meta name="description" content="Modern admin is super flexible, powerful, clean &amp; modern responsive Angular 15+ Bootstrap 5 Template with unlimited possibilities with bitcoin dashboard.">
  <meta name="keywords" content="admin template, modern admin template, dashboard template, flat admin template, responsive admin template, web app, crypto dashboard, bitcoin dashboard">
  <meta name="author" content="EvolVision &amp; CleVision
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, you have a `asp.net core API` project, and there is also an `Angular` frond-end project, and you currently want to compile Angular project and put it in the `wwwroot` folder under the .net core project.

So we can refer to the structure of the SPA for processing.

```
namespace NETAPI
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            // Add services to the container.

            builder.Services.AddControllers();
            // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
            builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
            builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

            var app = builder.Build();

            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            //if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            //{
            //    app.UseSwagger();
            //    app.UseSwaggerUI();
            //}

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseAuthorization();


            app.MapControllers();
            app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

            app.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can build/publish your angualr project, and we can get below files then paste then into `wwwroot` folder(if not this folder,we need to create it manually).

[image]

[image]

**Tips**

If you find the startup url is `swagger/index.html`, we can change it in `launchSettings.json`.

[image]