Error App Web .Net 8.0 when is published on server VPS ubuntu 23.04
Good morning, I have a problem with my web application developed on the frontend in Vue3 and jointly compiled on the backend with .net 8.0. When I publish and upload the files to the VPS server it identifies it correctly but I am getting a 404 error when trying to read the .js and .css assets files. What should I do?
I have this configuration on ngix default:
enter image description here
And when i run it i don't have errors
enter image description here
I have this errors
enter image description here
I try a lot of changes, but i can´t solve it

Welcome to SO.
Please read this guidance on how to ask a question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then edit your question (for example, remove the image links).
As written the question is not self-contained.
Hope this helps :)

You should consider to use UseStaticFiles in your .net 8.0 webapi project. And put the publish files of frontend into wwwroot folder. For more details, you can refer this thread. https://stackoverflow.com/a/78020750/7687666
